# How to ue getIntExtra without putextra?

Tags: android

I am following an example in a book about android programming

the example has one Activity ....

One of the method in the example has one line of code :

```
return getIntent().getIntExtra("KitchenDroid.Question", 0);
```

and I am confused about this line

as I learned before that we need to putExtra in an Intent and then getExtra later

but in the whole code there is no putExtra  .

thanks in advance

Comment: You are correct. There *must* be a `putExtra()` *somewhere* in order for `getExtra()` to return a meaningful value. This will be in the code that creates the `Intent` to start the `Activity`.

Answer (score 1):

all you would get is the default value (0 in this case) if the extra is not in the intent

Answer (score 1):

When you use getIntent() you are getting the intent that started the current activity. That means that the "KitchenDroid.Question" should be put in the intent in another Activity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityToStart.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("KitchenDroid.Question", "12");
i.putExtras(b);
startActivity(i);
```

If you have the code that starts the current activity, check it if it's there. If you don't have that code the author must have assumed that the other activity is responsible of passing that parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The `putExtra()` method should be in the code that creates the intent which is used to launch the activity, not in the activity code itself.

Answer (score 1):

from the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntExtra%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

```
public int getIntExtra (String name, int defaultValue)
```

Retrieve extended data from the intent.

here

**name**    :   The name of the desired item.

**defaultValue**    : the value to be returned if no value of the desired type is stored with the given name.

> It returns the value of an item that previously added with putExtra()
>   or the default value if none was found.

The last line is the answer of your question